# MongoDB fsyncUnlock won't unlock occasionally on Windows

Tags: backup, mongodb, windows, snapshot

We have a MongoDB replica set installed on Windows servers, with a scheduled backup job. MongoDB is configured to use journaling.

The job runs `db.fsyncLock()` via script on MongoDB (primary server), then performs a Kaminario file-system snapshot, then runs `db.syncUnlock()` via script.

The lock/unlock are separately, therefore not using the same connection.

The problem is that the `db.fsyncUnlock()` doesn't always work, leaving the database locked to writes until it is manually unlocked via shell.

We attempted to perform snapshots without using `fsyncLock()`, however, our tests showed that:

1. Restoring a single database-only resulting in the data having "holes" in it (some of the writing thread had non-committed changes followed by committed changes)
2. Restoring the entire database instance the restore failed due to a lock and missing journal, despite the journal being enabled and present

Whereas, with `fsyncLock()` the tests passed. The tests were performed with `writeConcern`=`2`, as we want to ensure persistency in case of a crash on MongoDB.

My questions are:

a. How to guarantee success of the `fsyncUnlock()` after performing the snapshot?

b. Is there any way to guarantee a consistent backup without using `fsyncLock()`?

Cross submitted [on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/q/702859/74444).

**Edit:**
After further investigation, it looks like the problem was with the snapshot hanging, not the unlock. However, that still doesn't explain the fsync requiring the lock.

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using (and if MongoDB 3.0, what storage engine)?

Comment: @Stennie MongoDB 3.0.1 (x64), mmapv1